# How to disable caching on rails helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My helper files code is being cached, making me have to restart the server every time a change is made, even in development. In my development.rb:

```
config.cache_classes = false

config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

How do I solve this problem. I am using rails 5. Let me know about the other details needed, I will update the question accordingly.